# Problem with videos in a 2013 asset library

Tags: document-library, video, asset-library

I have a SharePoint 2013 asset library that has developed a strange problem. No matter what video a user selects, the most recent video plays. Even stranger, the thumbnail from a different video appears briefly before the video plays. If you edit properties on a video and choose Manage Renditions, each video has a URL that will work for that video. So the videos themselves are not corrupt.